# Swapping away from Sequence Render

Tags: rendering, animation, video-sequence-editor

I rendered an animation and then placed it into the video sequence editor to test it, and rendered that as a video.

Now I want to render a second animation (in other words, keep working), but when I press render animation, it's still using the sequence render option? (Rendering it as pngs). I was wondering how to switch between sequence render and animation render properly?

Comment: I have no answer to your question, but exactly for this I always create new .blend file for work in sequence editor.

Answer (score 6):

You can turn Sequencer render on and off, as well as the compositor, by toggling these properties in the Scene Render Properties panel.

[image: VSE render switch]

You can choose to render in frame sequence or a video codec here. All you do is feed a different source to the render engine.