# Blender rendering video sequence instead of scene

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

This is an embarrassing basic problem, but I can't find the option to render my scene instead of what I'm working on in the video editor.

Every time I try to render my scene, it just renders what ever key frame I'm on in my video timeline.

Where is the option to switch between the two?

EDIT:  I found a Q/A for this.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/81087/33487

In short Properties Panel > Render > Post Processing > Sequencer

Comment: If you solved your problem, go ahead and add an answer to your question to help others with the same issue

Comment: I was hoping someone would just mark it as a duplicate so it would forward when found.